# sprintf - repeating arguments

Tags: php, printf

I want to format a string with `sprintf` but repeating many times an argument. see..

```
$str = "Str 1: %s - Str 2: %s - Str 2 again: %s";
```

Considering that string to format, I want to repeat the second arg two times.

```
echo sprintf($str, "I'm string 1", "My name is string 2");
```

And the wanted result like:

```
Str 1: I'm string 1 - Str 2: My name is string 2 - Str 2 again: My name is string 2
```

There's a way to do that??

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's all in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/sprintf)!

```
$str = 'Str 1: %1$s - Str 2: %2$s - Str 2 again: %2$s';
echo sprintf($str, "I'm string 1", "My name is string 2");
```

Note: Use single quotes for the format string otherwise you'll get **PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: s in /path/to/tofile:line**

You can also escape the `$` with a `\` if you are using double quotes.